# Does the Sermon on the Mount say women may not divorce their husbands for adultery?

Tags: literalism, divorce, sermon-on-the-mount

> 31 “It has been said, ‘Anyone who divorces his wife must give her a
> certificate of divorce.’[f] 32 But I tell you that anyone who divorces
> his wife, except for sexual immorality, makes her the victim of
> adultery, and anyone who marries a divorced woman commits adultery.
> (Matthew 5, NIV)

It's common to see people say "obviously, this applies if the roles are reversed" but in a conservative/literal reading of the bible, we're on shaky ground to ever say "obviously it means X" if it doesn't explicitly say X.

From other commonly quoted verses on divorce, I do not find *any* situation where a woman is explicitly said to be able to divorce her husband. We have sections which say remarriage is adultery in any circumstances (no mention of infidelity):

> 10 And in the house the disciples asked him again about this matter.
> 11 And he said to them, “Whoever divorces his wife and marries another
> commits adultery against her, 12 and if she divorces her husband and
> marries another, she commits adultery.” (Mark 10, NIV)

I know Christians who adhere very strictly to the letter of what's written, and they would argue that while a man *may* divorce a cheating wife, she cannot divorce a cheating husband.

Are there verses I have missed? *Is* it valid to say we can interchange husband/wife here and if so why/why not?